# If no annual observation use monthly average

Tags: r

I have some data that contains yearly observations, some states only have monthly, and some have both. I'd like to use the yearly observations, but if no yearly exists then use the monthly average. I could run a loop through, but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

**Sample data**

```
newdat <- data.frame(state = c("co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co"), year = c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001), 
                  type = c("year", "month", "month", "month", "month", "month"),
                  value = c(6,6,10,5,2,9))
```

**Desired output**

```
  state year type value
1    co 2000 year   6.0
2    co 2001 year   5.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
library(tidyverse)
newdat %>%
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  summarise(
    value = ifelse(
      "year"%in%type, 
      value[type=="year"], 
      mean(value[type=="month"])), 
    type="year")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   state [?]
#    state  year    value  type
#   <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
# 1     co  2000 6.000000  year
# 2     co  2001 5.333333  year
```

Comment: Yup, that did it!  Thanks!